# Why does Python not print what I ask it to print while in a loop?

Tags: python

I have a code where I iterate a certain scheme using a loop. At each iteration I want a printout of what happened. A silly minimal working example is shown below:

```
import time
Iter=0
for k in range(1,10):
    Iter=Iter+1 
    print('At iteration ',Iter,': k=',k,'.',sep='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

The `time.sleep(1)` is there to make my problem visible for such a short iteration scheme: At each iteration, the `print()` function only prints the first string. The rest appears only after the `print()` function is called in the next iteration. If I use the exact same syntax for the `print()` function outside of the loop, then I obtain the output I want. How can I get the same output when I'm inside the loop?

I'm new at this, but I suspect it could be relevant that I use the Anaconda3 (64-bit) distribution of Python 3.5 with the Spyder IDE on a Win10 machine.

Edit 1: SOLVED using the suggestion by @RemcoGerlich: "Try adding 'import sys' and then after the print sys.stdout.flush()." Many thanks!

Comment: Try adding 'import sys' and then after the print `sys.stdout.flush()`. Maybe it's buffering the output.

Comment: What do you mean by "only prints the first string"? Are you saying it only prints `At iteration `, and the rest of the line only shows up after a second has passed?

Comment: Thought this was interesting so tried it on my machine. Using IDLE on Python 3.5, Win8 & it outputs all 9 lines entirely fine.

Comment: Can you provide some expected output?

Comment: What @RemcoGerlich said should work try it out and comment results

Comment: Cannot reproduce in the console on Python3.5.

Comment: What output are you getting exactly? Do you mean that you get `"At iteration "`, then `"1: k=1. At iteration "` ?

Comment: Edit 1: SOLVED using the suggestion by @RemcoGerlich: "Try adding 'import sys' and then after the print sys.stdout.flush()." Many thanks!